# Sign SOAP message with WS security in Gatling

Tags: gatling, ws-security

[image]Is it possible to sign a SOAP Message with WS security in Gatling?
I got an working example i SOAPUI, but in that tool it is "built in" as a function.

Comment: Did you try set your certificates and etc. in `gatling.conf`?
https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/ssl/#configuring-keystore-and-truststore

Comment: Hm, no I have not tried that. Do you have an example?

Comment: Here is this default gatling.conf https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L62
Just provide path to your jks file, password and etc. 

(I warn you in advance: I have not worked with this case (soap and ssl), but it will be a good starting point to try)

Comment: But you did post this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593941/how-can-one-execute-java-code-using-gatling-load-testing-framework
. How can if I want to execute some java code that does the "sign certificate" per user it is not possible because we only have before() and after() hooks. I want to run some piece of java code for each virtual user

Comment: Have you tried set SSL via gatling.conf (above)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "set SSL". I am well aware of the conf-file, but I do not understand how that would help when I need to sign each request with WS-security? Please elaborate...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237642/discussion-between-amerousful-and-magnus-jensen).